# vba delete row not working properly

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to modify the data in a work sheet with some VBA, unfortunately the following code I'm using is not working properly.
Basically column A has the text, and I want to delete the entire row if the column A is "Pit" (not containing "Pit", but only "Pit"). For some reason the code is only deleting some rows but not others, so I have to keep running the script a few times to get rid of all the "Pit"s. There is nothing distinctly different between the rows it deletes and the ones it does not, they are all text & no spaces. There are thousands of rows with different column A text. Here is the code, I would greatly appreciate any suggestions.

```
Sub Pitdelete()

Dim lastrow As Long
Dim datasheet As Worksheet
Dim i As Long

Set datasheet = Worksheets("DefCatCou")

lastrow = datasheet.Range("a" & datasheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastrow
If datasheet.Cells(i, 1) = "Pit" Then
datasheet.Rows(i & ":" & i).EntireRow.delete
End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel VBA deleting rows in a for loop misses rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43454139/excel-vba-deleting-rows-in-a-for-loop-misses-rows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just loop backwards when deleting rows:

```
Sub Pitdelete()

Dim lastrow As Long
Dim datasheet As Worksheet
Dim i As Long

Set datasheet = Worksheets("DefCatCou")

lastrow = datasheet.Range("a" & datasheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = lastrow To 2 step -1 'This should fix it.
    If datasheet.Cells(i, 1) = "Pit" Then
        datasheet.Rows(i & ":" & i).EntireRow.delete
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Reason is that when you delete a row and increase the `i` with one, you basically skip the next row, since the delete shifted that one up.

The alternative is to add `i = i - 1` after the `EntireRow.Delete` line.

Comment: Cool, thanks for including the step -1, I didn't know how to do that!

Comment: I think i would suggest to focus on step -1, adding it did help me run my code.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you delete a row all the rows below it move up.

You can declare another variable like this and increase it each time you delete row:

```
Dim c as Integer
c = 0
If datasheet.Cells(i, 1) = "Pit" Then
datasheet.Rows(i - c & ":" & i - c).EntireRow.delete
c = c + 1
...
```

Comment: ahh I see. In that case would it work if I directly manipulate i? ie. i=i-1 rather than including c?

Comment: Technically you can, but this seems cleaner to me :)

Answer (score 0):

@zipa is quite right - when you delete a row, the others move up, changing their index.  As an alternative to his proposal, you can get the loop to run in reverse:

```
For i = lastrow To 2 Step -1
    If datasheet.Cells(i, 1) = "Pit" Then
        datasheet.Rows(i & ":" & i).EntireRow.delete
    End If
next i
```

That way, if you delete a row, it won't affect the next index in your loop.

Comment: You need to add `Step -1` in loop declaration.

Comment: ahh, very clever!

Comment: Ah - thanks @EganWolf.  You are quite right.  Fixed.